# Angularjs orderBy: how to call default comparator from custom sort function

Tags: angularjs, sql-order-by, comparator

I have a custom sort function to convert strings to numbers for one column in a grid. The other columns are comprised of strings or date values. I have a custom sort function which checks for the number column and performs the conversion, but for the other values I want the default comparator's behavior. How do I achieve this?

```js
$scope.sort = function (keyname) {
  $scope.sortKey = keyname;
  $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
};


$scope.sortSubGrid = function (a, b) {
  if ($scope.sortKey === 'caseNumber') {
    return = parseInt(b.value) -parseInt(a.value);
  }
  else {
    return = a.value > b.value;
  }
};
```

```html
<tr dir-paginate="agreement in agreements|orderBy:sortKey:reverse:sortSubGrid" ...>
```

The second half of the sortSubGrid function is intended to sort the non-numeric columns, but isn't achieving the results I expect, which is simply the results the default comparator provides. How do I get the default behavior for this second clause?

Answer (score 0):

According to the code in [orderBy.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/filter/orderBy.js) you can use either the default or the custom but no both as you describe, it would be a nice functionality though.

```
// Define the `compare()` function. Use a default comparator if none is specified.
var compare = isFunction(compareFn) ? compareFn : defaultCompare;
```

So you can always get the original defaultCompare code and modify it.

```
// source orderBy.js
function defaultCompare(v1, v2) {
  var result = 0;
  var type1 = v1.type;
  var type2 = v2.type;

  if (type1 === type2) {
    var value1 = v1.value;
    var value2 = v2.value;

    if (type1 === 'string') {
      // Compare strings case-insensitively
      value1 = value1.toLowerCase();
      value2 = value2.toLowerCase();
    } else if (type1 === 'object') {
      // For basic objects, use the position of the object
      // in the collection instead of the value
      if (isObject(value1)) value1 = v1.index;
      if (isObject(value2)) value2 = v2.index;
    }

    if (value1 !== value2) {
      result = value1 < value2 ? -1 : 1;
    }
  } else {
    result = type1 < type2 ? -1 : 1;
  }

  return result;
}
```